# R Data.Table Indexing Previous Cell Value

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create a variable (below) within a data table:

`Prob_RF_RR:`   probability that subject chose rich on a rich trial following a rich feedback trial §

In the context of the script/data; `"long" = rich`, `z = response` to `rich` stimuli

Sample of the data:

[image: sample of data]

For the variable I need to index the previous [condition] cell to see if it contains the condition equal to “long”. I believe the line should be something like this:

```
Prob_RF_RR=.SD[previous"long"=="long" & condition=="long" & response==z ... ]
```

How do I reference the previous cell in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data ( .SD ?) is in order of trial number, you can use `zoo` to turn the dataset into a time series object and create a lagged variable for condition.  For example:

```
library(zoo)
.SD <- zoo( .SD )
.SD$PreviousCondition <- c(NA , lag( .SD$condition ) )
.SD <- as.data.frame( .SD )
Prob_RF_RR <- .SD[condition == PreviousCondition & condition=="long" & response==z ... ]
```

Comment: Ahhh, interesting. Thanks!